# Why am I getting a QueryFailedError when controller method is not calling the db (PostgreSql)?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm developing a project in which among other things I have to connect to Binance for retrieving all the trades made by the user and other stuff. Everything was working well until at a certain point (without modifying the existing methods) I started to get an UUID error when I call some method inside a users controller.

In this example, I want to get my Binance Info and I'm calling the following endpoint:

```
@hasRoles(UserRole.ADMIN, UserRole.USER)
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get("/binanceAccount")
async account()
    {
        console.log("flag");
        const response = await this.userService.userBinanceAccInfo();

        if(!response.isResponse)
        {
            this.errorResponse([response.errors.toString()]);
        } 

        return { account: response.accountInfo };
    }
```

It should return the Binance account info and printing the flag but instead of that, I'm getting this error and the flag is not printed in the console. The thing is that I don't know why I'm getting this error even I'm not calling my database inside this or other methods.

```
[Nest] 55510   - 04/29/2021, 4:57:06 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] invalid input syntax for type uuid: "binanceAccount" +6913ms
QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "binanceAccount"
at new QueryFailedError (/projectPath/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:12:28)
at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (/projectPath/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:248:31)
at step (/projectPath/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
at Object.throw (/projectPath/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
at rejected (/projectPath/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:69)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

For more testing, I tried this and I got the same error as above:

```
@Get("/binanceAccountTest")
    async account1()
    {
        console.log("test");
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to set a field marked as a uuid to `binanceAccount`, which is not a valid uuid.

Comment: But in the case of the "binanceAccountTest"  method I'm not setting anything and I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: try passing a UUID in the binanceAccount(controller) and accordingly change the parameter in the service just to see if it works.